# Handbrake stackdump while converting video

Tags: handbrake

[**Handbrake**](http://handbrake.fr/) dumps its stack on me when I try to resize a video file. The original file size is 2.7GB and the **Target Size** is 700MB. No other settings of the video are being changed (left at default). Pass 1 of the encoding goes through, but **HandbrakeCLI** dumps on Pass 2.

I am using Handbrake 0.9.3. I get this error no matter what target file format (AVI, MKV, etc.) I choose. Is there anything I can do to get around this error and successfully resize the video file?

The contents of **HandBrakeCLI.exe.stackdump**:

```
Exception: STATUS_ACCESS_VIOLATION at eip=0091896B
eax=00000000 ebx=01593BB8 ecx=19E6CCA4 edx=19E6CCA0 esi=015F89E0 edi=01591B58
ebp=00000000 esp=19E6CA10 program=C:\Program Files\HandBrake\HandBrakeCLI.exe, pid 1732, thread unknown (0xE14)
cs=001B ds=0023 es=0023 fs=003B gs=0000 ss=0023
Stack trace:
Frame     Function  Args
End of stack trace
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you should send them a bug report, it looks like Handbrake is using trac so try to submit it there.

- http://trac.handbrake.fr/